# How to Include Multiple Product IDs in a PHP Action

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I need to add multiple product ids for one function.

I've looked online for the answer and haven't been able to find anything. I'm new to PHP so apologizes if this is a super easy answer.

Below is the code that I am currently using and it works for 1 product Id.

```php
add_action ('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button','room_number_title',90);
function room_number_title() {
   global $product;


    if( $product->get_id() != 2797 ) return;

    echo '   <h3>Select Number of Rooms (Max Occupancy Per Room: 4)</h3> 
   </br>';
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question , it is not clear.

Comment: Please also tag it as a wordpress question

Comment: Yes, basically this function adds the <h3> to the woocommerce hook that I have chosen. Right now I have it going to just a specific product (2797). I want it to go to multiple product ids that I choose.

Comment: Tagged as a wordpress question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the product ids to an array and use the php function `in_array()`.

```
$product_ids_to_add_h3_to = array(2797, 1111, 2222, 3333);

if(!in_array($product->get_id(), $product_ids_to_add_h3_to)) return;
```

[in_array php function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)